# Understanding Eureka peer-to-peer communication

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am working with microservices and netflix oss. I am using Eureka for service registry and discovery. I am trying out different options to understand behaviour of Eureka server. I still have some doubts with respect to below mentioned scenario.

I have couple of microservices, Service-A and Service-B. I also have two Eureka server instances viz. Eureka-1(port:8761) and Eureka-2(port:8762). I have registered both services with only Eureka-1. Also, service-A is invoking Service-B using eureka service instance name.

When I run Service-A, Service-B, Eureka-1 and Eureka-2 services, I am able to hit Service-A which internally hitting Service-B as expected. However, when I take Eureka-1 instance down and hit service-A, it still able to hit Service-B internally using eureka service instance name. My question is does Eureka-2 instance come to know about services registered with Eureka-1 instance. If yes, how and when does this communication happens between Eureka server instances?? Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good write up on the Netflix site (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication) that explains how eureka peer to peer happens.
If you have both eureka-1 and eureka-2 pointing at each other (i.e. their eureka client definition in the yml files), then when you register to eureka-1, eureka-2 will get the list of available services from eureka-1.
So once paired, eureka-2 will have the same list as eureka-2 and discovery will work.
You should probably put your eureka-1 and 2 configuration in your question so we have more detail